# I want to access and sum the values of a pointer array, but I get the wrong values

Tags: c, function, pointers

In my program the user allocates a number of random float values to a pointer array.
After that I wish to use the values generated in the array in a function to calculate the mean-value, but I dont get the correct values

This is what I use to allocate random float numbers to the pointer *arr

```
for (int i = 0; i < antalVarde; i++)
    {
        if (i % 10 == 0)
            printf("\n");

        *arr = RandomReal(low, high);
        printf("%.1f ", *arr);
    }
```

And this is my function to calculate the mean-value.

```
float mean(int antalVarde, float *arr)
{
    float medel = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < antalVarde; i++)
    {
        medel = medel + *(arr + i);
    }
    medel = medel / antalVarde;
    return medel;
}
```

When I debug while stepping-into the code it gets messed up when I get to

```
medel = medel + *(arr + i);
```

Can this not be used to access the values in a pointer array?

Forgive me if it's a poorly asked question.
grateful for answers.

Comment: What's `RandomReal`? What's `low` and `high` ? Where is your `main` function?

Comment: Its better to provide a [mcve].  It helps those that would like to help you.

Comment: RandomReal allocates random float values to the array. low and high are the range between those float values.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mcve].

Comment: @csnoob don't describe your code, show it.

Comment: Maybe `*arr = RandomReal(low, high);` -> `*(arr + i) = RandomReal(low, high);` and `printf("%.1f ", *arr);`. -> `printf("%.1f ", *(arr + i));` It's just a guess, there might be more problems elsewhere in some code you didn't show.

Comment: For a pointer or array `arr`, `*arr` is equal to `arr[0]`. The loop assigns your random value to the same element, leaving the others possibly uninitialized and with indeterminate values.

Comment: General hint: instead of writing `*(arr + i)` you should rather write `arr[i]`, both do exactly the same thing, but latter is more readable for human beings.

Comment: Thank you @Someprogrammerdude, this was the fix.
the question got answered using the information provided.
Wouldn't that mean it was a decently formulated question?

Answer (score 0):

You don't increment pointer `arr` in the initialisation loop. Only the first `float` at the addresse pointed by `arr` is written.

Comment: Yes, this fixed it. Changed *arr to arr[i]. Thank you for your help!